# Bootstrap fluid layout on wordpress issue

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Hi Is there any of you out there that is able to assist me on this. I'm experimenting with the fluid layout of bootstrap on my wordpress site. Apparently the  isn't working properly. I created a .span 12 column and its not taking up the full width of the browser. Instead its width shrank. Is there a way around this?

Heres the experiment which i created using a custom page template

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: page-work
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>    
<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

<style type="text/css">

.span12{
    background:black;
    color:white;
    padding:20px 0;
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:15px;
}

.span6{
    background:blue;
    color:white;
    padding:20px 0;
    text-align:center;
        margin-top:15px;
}

</style>

<div class="container-fluid">

   <div class="row-fluid">

     <div class="span12">span 12</div>

</div>

   <div class="row-fluid">

     <div class="span6">span 6</div>
     <div class="span6">span 6</div>

   </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you recreate your problem in a jsfiddle or link to your site? I'd recommend not styling the actual Bootstrap span6, span12 classes etc. Best to use those for your grid only and place other elements within them and style those elements. That will keep your code much easier to understand and organise.

Comment: Generally speaking the top-most parent will not take the full-width of the screen. It will add a half gutter margin to each side to keep your content from touching the browser's chrome.

Comment: Billy Moat: Hi thks for the reply, the styling is just for temporary. Anyway heres the link http://designbyjourney.com/work/

Comment: Dawson: I've removed the parent and problem still persist.

Comment: Anyways, don't think jsfiddle can work this out, i'm using a bootstrap framework on wordpress.

Comment: Issue solved. Anyways its not wordpress issue, just some scripting blunder. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This is because bootstrap has a fixed width of span12 as

```
.span12 {
    width: 1170px;
  }
```

for bigger screens.

If you still want, you can try this:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .span12 {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Always create a child css file and put that below the bootstrap file.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend upgrading to Bootstrap 3 as it handles fluid-containers in a much better way and you wouldn't have this problem in the first place.

.span12 becomes col-xx-12 (xx is either xs, sm, md and lg...read up on that!) and has a width of 100%. BS3 uses percentage widths rather than fixed widths as mentioned in the answer above. It's also not too difficult to move from BS2 to 3.

- http://getbootstrap.com/ - download here
- http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/ - documentation

As a general rule, wordpress won't really change how your website looks. It's the styles you put around it so Wordpress in this case is irrelevant.